# ¿Porque graba dos veces?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, crud

estoy haciendo una aplicación, algo sencillo, pero en la parte donde se agregan registros me está guardando 2 veces el mismo registro, siempre lo he hecho de la misma forma, pero ahora, cuando inserto un registro desde el formulario, en la base de datos se guarda dos veces.

Estoy usando PHP con MySQL.

El jQuery:

```
$('#frmPropietarioNuevo').submit(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();

   var data = $('#frmPropietarioNuevo').serialize();
   var ajaxURL = base_url + 'Propietarios/setPropietario';

   $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: ajaxURL,
       data: data,
       success: function(response) {
           var objData = JSON.parse(response);

           if (objData.status) {
               $('#frmPropietarioNuevo')[0].reset();
               swal.fire("Propietarios", objData.msg, "success");
               tablePropietarios.ajax.reload();
               $.fancybox.close();
           } else {
               swal.fire("Error", objData.msg, "error");
           }
       }
   });
});
```

El controlador:

```
public function setPropietario() {

    $txtCondominioPro = intval($_POST["txtCondominioPro"]);
    $txtDniPro = strClean($_POST["txtDniPro"]);
    $txtNombresPro = strClean($_POST["txtNombresPro"]);
    $txtEmailPro = strClean($_POST["txtEmailPro"]);
    $txtEmail2Pro = strClean($_POST["txtEmail2Pro"]);
    $txtTelefonoPro = strClean($_POST["txtTelefonoPro"]);
    $txtTelefono2Pro = strClean($_POST["txtTelefono2Pro"]);
    $txtPwsPro = md5($_POST["txtPwsPro"]);
    $txtEstadoPro = 1;

    $requestPropietario = $this -> model -> insertPropietario($txtCondominioPro, $txtDniPro, $txtNombresPro, $txtEmailPro, $txtEmail2Pro, $txtTelefonoPro, $txtTelefono2Pro, $txtPwsPro, $txtEstadoPro);

    if ($requestPropietario == "Existe") {
        $arrResponse = array('status' => false, 'msg' => '¡Atención! El propietario ya existe');
    } else if ($requestPropietario > 0) {
        $to = $txtEmailPro;
        $subject = "Bienvenido a Grupo La Masia";
        $message = 'Bla bla bla';
        $headers[] = 'MIME-Version: 1.0';
        $headers[] = 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1';
        $headers[] = 'From: Condominio <no-replay@condominio.com>';

        mail($to, $subject, $message, implode("\r\n", $headers));

        $arrResponse = array('status' => true, 'msg' => 'Se ha registrado satisfactoriamente. Revise el correo electrónico que registró, le hemos enviado un mensaje de bienvenida y sus datos de acceso para que los tenga presente.');
    } else {
        $arrResponse = array('status' => false, 'msg' => 'No es posible almacenar los datos');
    }

    echo json_encode($arrResponse, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
    die();

}
```

El modelo:

```
public function insertPropietario(int $condominio, string $dni, string $nombres, string $email, string $email2, string $telefono, string $telefono2, string $pws, int $estado) {

    $return = "";
    $this -> conPropietario = $condominio;
    $this -> dniPropietario = $dni;
    $this -> nomPropietario = $nombres;
    $this -> emaPropietario = $email;
    $this -> em2Propietario = $email2;
    $this -> telPropietario = $telefono;
    $this -> te2Propietario = $telefono2;
    $this -> pwsPropietario = $pws;
    $this -> estPropietario = $estado;

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM propietarios WHERE condominio = {$this -> conPropietario} AND dni = '{$this -> dniPropietario}'";
    $request = $this -> Select($sql);

    if (!empty($request)) {
        $return = "Existe";
    } else {
        $query_insert = "INSERT INTO propietarios (condominio, dni, nombres, email, email2, pws, telefono, telefono2, estado) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
        $arrData = array($this -> conPropietario, $this -> dniPropietario, $this -> nomPropietario, $this -> emaPropietario, $this -> em2Propietario, $this -> pwsPropietario, $this -> telPropietario, $this -> te2Propietario, $this -> estPropietario);
        $request_insert = $this -> Insert($query_insert, $arrData);

        $return = $request_insert;
    }

    return $return;

}
```

Espero que me puedan ayudar porque lo he revisado muchas veces y no logro ver que cosa podría estar pasando.

¿Hay alguna razón por la cual esto pueda estar sucediendo?

En otros lugares donde uso lo mismo, graba una sola vez, pero en esta aplicación es donde me graba dos veces.

Saludos,

Comment: Buen día, así sin ver nada de lo que estás haciendo no podríamos adivinar. ¿Haz revisado la documentación? Si estás utilizando versiones más nuevas es posible que haya habido cambios.

Comment: Si, la razon es porque de alguna forma lo estas grabando dos veces... mucho mas que adivinar la razon, no podemos hacer...

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: es el dns, siempre es el dns

Comment: a la funcion de submit ademas del preventdefault es conveniente agregarle un return false ya que el manejo de success/error lo tenes dentro del ajax y eso evitaría la propagación del evento. dependiendo de cómo sea el form podes tener varios elementos que disparan el submit, ahi puede estar la diferencia entre proyectos o puede que se esten enganchando dos listeners ( iguales ) al submit.  como ultima medida podes usar el pattern `.off('submit').on('submit', function(e){})` ( que limpia los handlers agregados por jquery antes de agregar el nuevo)

Comment: @aloMalbarez donde debería poner el `return false`, lo del pattern, te refieres a que debería ir asi? `$('#frmPropietarioNuevo').off('submit').on('submit', function(e){})`

Comment: el return false es al final de la function del submit. al dispararse el evento entra en la funcion, se setea el prevent default, se dispara el ajax ( q retornara valor en algun momento y sigue su ruta ) y por ultimo retornas "false" para que el evento no siga propagandose . el pattern si, es una forma de enganchar y desenganchar manejadores de eventos el .off('nombrevento') sólo desengancha los eventos agregados con .on('nombreevento') pero es una forma de filtrar "doble enganches"

Comment: @aloMalbarez muchas gracias, es algo nuevo que he aprendido hoy, pero me hizo pensar lo primero que pusiste que pudiera estar enganchándose dos listener y me puse a revisar y tenía otro archivo js donde se disparaba un submit al mismo form, lo quité y ahora funciona muy bien. Nuevamente muchas gracias.

Comment: elimina o comenta todo el codigo del ajax y pon un `console.log("pase por aqui");` si se imprime dos veces, significa que el evento "submit" se esta disparando dos veces por algun motivo, y se esta pasando por los egg el preventdefault, ya a mi me paso una vez y tuve que hacerme de un apaño implementando namespace en los eventos y limpieza de los mismos...

Comment: Abres la pagina, presiona F12 y vas al monitor de red. Guarda el form y mira cuantas veces envía el formulario al servidor. Si se ha enviado 2 veces el problema está en el cliente, caso contrario en el servidor